# Laravel eloquent subquery alias

Tags: subquery, laravel-5.1

How to do this in Laravel 5.1?

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT subscriber_id, COUNT(*) as count
        FROM mailing_group_subscriber
        WHERE mailing_group_id IN ('99', '15498855416270870')
    GROUP BY subscriber_id
) table_count
WHERE count = 2;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not using having, thus it will count all and pick the count is 2. So, get all counts, and pick count 2 via collection:

```
DB::table('mailing_group_subscriber')
  ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count'))
  ->select('subscriber_id')
  ->groupBy('subscriber_id')
  ->whereIn('mailing_group_id', ['99', '15498855416270870'])
  ->pluck('count', 'subscriber_id')
  ->where('count', 2);
```